# i'm facing issues to create a postgresql plpython3u extension

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython

i'm facing issues in creating extension plpython3u in postgresql 11

`create extension plpython3u`

ERROR:

> could not load library "C:/Program
>   Files/PostgreSQL/11/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not
>   be found.

SQL state: XX000

But the **"plpython3.dll"** file was available at the specified path.

Comment: You need Python 3.6 (64 bit) and the library `python36.dll` on PATH.

Comment: i have searched the whole pc. i can't find out the python36.dll file.

Comment: where can i get python36.dll.

Comment: Download `Python 3.6.7` `Windows x86-64 executable installer` from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ and install it.

Comment: python36.dll found.. i just copied to system32 dir.. the extension installed successfully. but i just created the postgresql function 

CREATE FUNCTION pymax (a integer, b integer)
  RETURNS integer
AS $$
  if a > b:
    return a
  return b
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
when i execute for save the function .. postgresql crashed.

 "Connection to the server has been lost."
how to fix.